# Objective c: Parsing string to float, avoid extra decimals

Tags: objective-c, floating-point, int

Im converting some information Im receiving by a string to a float to get the sum of all of them.

The problem is when I convert the float, for example:

```
myString = @"13502.63"
float *f = [myString floatValue];
NSLog(@"Converted %f", f);
```

The result of "f" is 13502.629883

This thing is ok for some values, but when I have to add a big amount of this values, these extra decimals make the result incorrect.

Could anybody help me, please?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean that the extra decimals make the result incorrect?

Comment: There are values that floats **cannot** represent exactly. When you try to store that value in a float, you actually get the *closest representable value*. When you perform a series of operations on a float, you can lose accuracy. Use `NSDecimalNumber` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately all floating point types in any language will have this problem, as they have to convert into an underlying binary integer format.

Have you considered using NSDecimalNumber?

These will be much slower than a float, but if that is not a problem, then they are much more accurate for such calculations.

If you need speed for some reason, would a double or long-double be accurate enough?

Comment: Just be careful, the double will increase the accuracy but the same aliasing effect might happen but in much smaller decimal places - if double is proving accurate enough for your application though - great.

Answer (score 2):

If you want accuracy you should not use float. Use [NSDecimalNumber](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDecimalNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

```
NSString *myString = @"13502.63";
NSDecimalNumber *number = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:myString];
```

Answer (score 1):

`float` numbers have no exact representation, that is the reason why "13502.63" is converted to 13502.629883; this is the closest float to the original number.

So, I don't think there is an easy solution with float. You should try `NSDecimalNumber`. I don't know about the performance, but it should give you an exact representation.

Comment: Could you please explain what closest float mean? Do floats come in discreet values? I mean, is 13502.630000 not a possible float?